# Save summary to text file in R

Tags: raster, r, export, geotiff-tiff, summarizing

I have more than 2000 TIFF files of an NDVI index. I would like to check if I made it properly and if all of values are between -1 and 1.

How can I save everything to a text file to check max and min values as a summary of all files to not do it one by one?

I was trying to use RasterStack to combine all files in one, but it does not work...

Any other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reference image files and a code sample with desired output (a.k.a. a minimum reproducible example) wld help folks help you.

Comment: you may do that right in R directly

Comment: Can you write a "for" loop over the raster file names? Do you know how to get a vector of all files from a folder? Then loop over those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may run a for loop, here the code takes two single rasters (out of rasterstacks) and puts their range in a data.frame

```
 a <- getData('worldclim', var='tmin', res=10)
    b <- getData('worldclim', var='tmax', res=10)
    a1 <- a$tmin1
    b1 <- b$tmax1
    ab <- list(a1,b1)
    cellStats(b1,"range")
    df <- data.frame()
    for(i in ab){
      df <- rbind(df, cellStats(i,"range"))
    }
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Outline solution:

```
rasters = list.files(pattern = "*.tif$")
ranges = do.call(
           rbind,
          lapply(
            rasters, 
            function(rname){r = raster(rname); range(r[])})
          )
```

For a working directory where I have two tif files, I get:

```
> ranges
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  47.14706 2109.250
[2,] 283.35699 2848.571
```